# How to pass a variable from ajax to nested ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I'm sending ajax call and getting an answer that I need from the first ajax then I want to pass my result to my nested ajax, my var (result) is null in the nested ajax/settimeout fun, can I pass it ? Am I missing something ?

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getCustomerGuidId", "Document")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: { "classNum": currentclassNum},
            contentType:'json' ,
            dataType:'text',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);**-> is fine - not null**.
// a or result is null when I hit the getCurrentDoc- function althought I get the data I need from getCustomerGuidId function 
                var a = result;-> tried to pass it to a new var..IDK.. I 
                                  thought it will help... it didn't.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("getCurrentDoc", "Document")',
                        contentType:'text',
                        data: a,-> here it's null
                        success: function (data) {
                        }
                    });                                                
                }, 2000);                                   
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail " + result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In setTimeout, function context got changed that's why a is null there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this will help to pass value to nested ajax call

```
function test(){
var myText = 'Hello all !!';

$.get({
    //used the jsonplaceholder url for testing 
    'url':'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    'method':'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        //updating value of myText
        myText = 'welcome';
        $.post({
            'url':'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            'method':'POST',
            //data.title is the return value from get request to the post request
            'data':{'title':data.title},
            'success':function (data) {
                alert(data.title +'\n' + myText);//your code here ...

            }
        });
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question and you've likely moved on, but there's still no accepted answer.

Your **setTimeout** takes an anonymous function, so you are losing your binding; if you have to use a Timeout for some reason, you need to add **.bind(this)** to your **setTimeout** call (see below)

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("getCurrentDoc", "Document")',
        contentType:'text',
        data: a,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });                                                
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

At a guess you're using a Timeout because you want to ensure that your promise (i.e. the first ajax call) is resolving prior to making the nested call.

If that's your intention, you can actually scrap **setTimeout** completely as you have the nested call in the first ajax **success** call, which only runs once the promise has been resolved (providing there isn't an error; if so, jQuery would call **error** rather than success)

Removing **setTimeout** means you won't lose your binding, and **a** should still be **result** (hopefully **a** is an object, otherwise your second call is also going to experience issues...)

Lastly, after overcoming the binding issue you wouldn't need **var a = result**; you should be able to pass **result** directly to your nested ajax call.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

In the nested ajax you send a as a param name, not as a param value.
So you can try the following (change `param` to actual param name which your server expects):

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getCustomerGuidId", "Document")',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { "classNum": currentclassNum},
        dataType:'text',
        success: function (result) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("getCurrentDoc", "Document")',
                    data: {param: result},
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });                                                
            }, 2000);                                   
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("fail " + result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still Null... :-/